# Send command from Tmux pane to Vim/Neovim

Tags: tmux

I wondered if there is a way to send a command from Tmux into any pane with the name of `nvim` or `vim`? The use case is to trigger a function which is defined in my `init.vim` file for toggling the colorscheme.

With `vim-tmux-navigator`, I know the two can work in harmony but I've never seen or heard of the use case where Tmux can trigger a Vim based function.

Comment: Really a tmux question not a vim question but you can send arbitrary keystrokes to any addressed window(s)/pane(s) with `tmux send-keys -l`. And you can determine which panes have a particular attribute (title, for instance) using `tmux list-panes -F fmtstring`.

Comment: (cont.) But there's nothing Vim specific about any of it.

Comment: Appreciate the feedback. Have removed vim tags for relevance and searching